# Sabre BFM V4 response not showing only First Class flights as specified

Tags: api, sabre

`I am using Sabre BFM V4 to search for flights and I want to display only First Class flights in the response. However, the response is currently showing all flight classes, including Economy and Premium Economy.

Here is an example of the request I am making:

```
{
  "OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ": {
    "TravelPreferences": {
      "CabinPref": [
        {
          "Cabin": "F",
          "PreferLevel": "Only"
        }
      ]
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

I have confirmed that there are First Class flights available in the database, and I have specified the preferred cabin class and preference level in the request. However, I am still not getting the desired results.

Is there anything I am missing or doing wrong in my request? How can I make sure that only First Class flights are displayed in the response?

In the example request, the user is trying to specify a preference for First Class flights only using the Sabre BFM V4 API. The request sets the "Cabin" parameter to "F" to indicate First Class and the "PreferLevel" parameter to "Only" to indicate that only flights with First Class cabins should be displayed.

The user is expecting the response to only show flights with First Class cabins, but is currently getting a response that includes all flight classes.

The user is seeking assistance to determine what is causing the unexpected result and how to correct it to achieve the desired outcome of only showing First Class flights.`

Answer (score 0):

Does your request have anything on jumpCabinLogic or keepSameCabin?

I believe that current shopping logic does not restrict the responses to the requested cabin and allows cabin jump (up or down). For this kind of scenario if you do not want to face with Jump Cabin Logic they must specify that in the request using the elements:
JumpCabinLogic Disabled="true" and KeepSameCabin Enabled="true"

**JumpCabinLogic Disabled="true"**

With this element Jump Cabin cannot be fully disabled. For two- and more- segment solutions where at least one segment offers preferred cabin, jump cabin will be performed for the segment where preferred cabin is not offered but the lower cabin is offered and available. This means that BFM might offer mixed cabins.

**KeepSameCabin Enabled="true"**

Set to "true" guarantees that all segments within single shopping option belong to the requested cabin. When KeepSameCabin Enabled = "true" is used in conjunction with JumpCabinLogic Disabled ="true", KeepSameCabin overrides JumpCabin parameter.This element supports multiple use cases, including the use case whereby a travel policy supports travel only in cabin requested, no upgrades allowed; eliminating unwanted options in the results.”